# Find mean of nested lists if it contains integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, nested-lists

I have a list containing nested lists. Some of the nested lists contain integers, and some of the nested lists contain strings. I would like to find the mean/average of only the nested list elements that contain integers. If that means removing the list that contain the strings and then adding them back later, that is fine, but I am also unable to figure out a way to do that without indexing.

The list would look something like this:

```
nested_list = [[217, 208], [4, 7], [2, 2], [325, 390], ['STR', 'STR'], [1, 6], [0, 3],
               ['ING','ING']]
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# importing mean() 
from statistics import mean
 
for list_ in nested_list:   # nested list iteration
    if isinstance(list_[0], int):  # checking integer list type within nested list
        print(mean(list_)) # printing integer list mean
    else:                      # pass the list which is not integer type
         pass
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you so much! How would I go about re-adding the list that was passed?

Comment: Are you talking about the nested list?  if yes, where would you like to add that nested list?

Comment: I would like to add it to a json dictionary along with the mean values that you helped me create

Comment: Pls share in details what all and in which fashion you wanted to do it.

Answer (score 1):

just loop through the lists and check for ints, append them to a list then calc the mean from that list.

```
from statistics import mean

def mean_from_nested_list:
    nums = []
    for l in nested_list:
        for item in l:
            if isinstance(item, int):
                sum.append(item)
    return mean(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is more basic code for novices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0AML.jpg)